# Elevar al cuadrado función con spline en Matlab

Tags: matlab

Mi pregunta es cómo puedo elevar al cuadrado una función hecha con spline para después integrarla. Os dejo el script aquí. La variable V es un vector 4801x1.

```
x=linspace(0,4800*835e-6,4801);
y=V;
spl=spline(x,y);
splint = fnint(spl);
for i=1:57
    ii=0.7+(i-1)*0.7
    A=diff(fnval(splint,[ii ii+1]))
    B=sqrt(A/0.7)
    Vef(i,:)=B
end
```